# Can a WSL distributions filesystem live entirely on a separate ext4 drive?

Tags: linux, ssd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My Laptop has 2 SSDs, one for Windows and another that I'd like to use for the WSL.

Is there a way I can format the second SSD as ext4 and make WSL use it as the root drive for the WSL?

That way all Linux-based file operations will occur in the ext4 drive and will only go through the WSL glue to NTFS when I'm cd'd into the NTFS file systems.

I've looked into `wsl --mount` but it doesn't seem to be what I'm entirely looking for (having the root of a WSL Distro on a separate drive entirely). And I'm currently running full Linux and am looking to switch to Windows assuming I can do something like this. This way I can hopefully get all the dev benefits of Linux with the UI stability of Windows (along with MS Office & Teams).

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: I've looked into `wsl --mount` but it doesn't seem to be what I'm entirely looking for (having the `root` of a WSL Distro on a separate drive entirely). And I'm currently running full Linux and am looking to switch to Windows assuming I can do something like this. This way I can hopefully get all the dev benefits of Linux with the UI stability of Windows (along with MS Office & Teams)

Comment: Welcome to the community. Rather than responding in comments, a better way is to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1767843/edit) the question as I now did. This way the relevant info is directly available for community members. I'd suggest taking the quick [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and checking the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) (at least Asking and Answering) to get a handle how these sites work and differ from discussion forums. Personally I don't think what you're asking is possible the way you'd like - WSL is a Windows Subsystem, after all.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Peregrino69; I'll be sure to keep this in mind in the future :)

Comment: Without knowing the SPECIFIC answer to this problem, the answer IS ALWAYS the same.  a) figure out where the "thingy" is sourced.  b)  move said thingy to another drive.  c)  Create a hardlink, soflink, junction back to it's original location.  No configuration (or registry) file changes. PERIOD. Works ALMOST 100% of the time (Linux,Windows,Mac).. Why *almost*?  Some things needs to be at a specific offset on a drive (like hibernation files) and will fail if a link sits there instead.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas He's not talking about relocating the VHDX file though, but something like SCSI passthrough in Hyper-V, apparently.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @TomYan :)  Have a great evening.